# How to replace multiple fields values with values from another table?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables: TableA

```
Id Status User
1   15    111
2   15    111
3   15    111
```

And TableB which contains history of status changes from previous table:

```
Id IdA Status   Date
1   1   10   2023-01-18
2   1   30   2022-12-18
3   3   30   2022-01-17
4   3   10   2022-01-16
```

What I need to do is to update status field values for every row with User 111 in TableA with values from TableB, I need to find the latest entity change in TableB and write its status to the corresponding entity in TableA.

So the final result for the TableA should be:

```
Id Status User
1    10   111
2    15   111
3    30   111
```

Comment: Do you mean 15 should become 10 for all user 111 rows in table A?

Comment: Is this some kind of recovery? (Odd design and scenario.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the reality I have to face at work now, I will try to remake the concept, but previous developers made it this way and I need to recover some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update tableA
set status = latest_data.status
from (select distinct on (idA)
       idA, status, date
      from   tableB
      -- helps to retrieve the latest update for each unique idA
      order by idA, date desc) latest_data
where latest_data.idA = tableA.id;
```

See the docs for **[DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)** clause.

See the [demo](https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yvaez4ae) with all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Rank table b based on IdA ordered by date ascending then choose row number 1 to update table a.

Row_number()over(order by ...)

tableb is the second table and the tablen is the 1 table

```
update tablen t1 set status = t2.status
from 
(select id, IDA, status from (
select *,
row_number ()over(partition by IDA order by daten desc) rnk
from tableb) x 
  where rnk = 1)t2 where t1.id = t2.idA;
```

this clause is to get the last update

```
select id, IDA, status from (
select *,
row_number ()over(partition by IDA order by daten desc) rnk
from tableb) x 
  where rnk = 1
```